# how can i give in large textual data in center of donut chart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNPvP.png) Here is my code where i want to display a huge data in center of the circle (like a unordered list) but am unable to do so, because chart is/can not allow[ing] a huge list like data in center of circle, i have gone through present solutions given out none helping me/ i am unable to understand.please help me out with a solution or any suggestion..!
Thanks..!!

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.1.min.js"></script>
<title>Morris.js Donut Chart Example</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- orris -->
<link href="css/plugins/morris/morris-0.4.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
.morris-chart{ 
  height:720px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="col-lg-12">
     <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
<div class="ibox-content">
  <div id="donut-example" class="morris-chart"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <script>

Morris.Donut({
  element: 'donut-example',
  data: [
    {label: "Sunil ", value: 30},
    {label: "Prajwal km", value: 35},
    {label: "Hari", value: 5},
    {label: "AARMS", value: 1}
  ]
});

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please if you can answer please answer..! do not use your reputation power to show that you can down vote or if you do so please leave a comment were i have gone wrong...!! ill take it positively

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Show a huge list of text in the center of a donut chart? What does that look like? Can you mock up the desired chart with a drawing app and show what you want the chart to look like? Your data sample works fine in the demo page from github.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Morris.js. The donut chart from that library shows the data for a single data point in the donut center. Hover over the donut segment and the label and value will show up in the center of the chart.

[image]

This chart is not designed to show more than one value in the center.

In any case, if you are trying to visualise data with more than three data points, don't use donut or pie charts. Use horizontal bar charts instead, where labels and values are next to each bar, for example like this:

[image]

Comment: Mam, here is the link http://i.stack.imgur.com/NNPvP.png to image...i want to achive something similar to it..!!

Comment: How many data items do you see in the middle of the donut? I see only one. Just like in your chart. What is the problem?

Comment: It's like unordered list at center..!!

Comment: Sorry, but that does not make sense. The center of the donut in morris.js ever only shows ONE (as in 1) data point. No list. Just one data point. The one that the mouse hovers over. That is how a morris.js donut works. If that is not what you want to achieve you may be working with the wrong tool. Even if you WANT something does not mean it is possible with the tool you have selected.